# Angular 8 + internationalization not working int AOT mode

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular2-aot

I am unable to make my locale files work in AOT mode for my application while it is perfectly fine for dev mode. Please help

Comment: Any error client/server side?

Comment: It is working if the i18n config is inside the module directly. But not working in case I put the config in a different file

Answer (score 0):

Angular i18n doesn't work with AOT. You need to build like this

```
 ng build --aot=false
```